# Tool for determining object custom field use

Tags: metadata

Is there a good tool that checks the schema to determine custom fields and their use in triggers, page layouts, classes, etc? We have a couple objects that are getting close to the 500 max and it would be nice if there were a better way than having someone get a list of custom fields for an object manually and then searching every page layout, class, and trigger for use of each field.

Comment: It isn't a tool, but deleting a field referenced in other places will cancel the deletion and tell you where the field is referenced, excluding dynamic references.

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly what you want but you can use FieldTrip, this App(free) checks all the records that match a given query and allows you to report on their usage. So you can tell which fields are being used and which ones are not really in use.

https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000003HSXEEA4

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any tools that automate this, but here are some ideas:

1. Try out [Field Trip](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000003HSXEEA4) to see how many of those fields are actually populated. If they have no data then they probably are not being used anywhere.
2. You could download your Metadata with Eclipse of the [Force.com IDE](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Force.com_IDE) and then use your favorite search tool to scour the XML files.

Comment: The problem is that the object is new and there isn't data in those fields. I've done this, sort of by using grep to get a list of fields in an object, saving that to a file, cleaning up the data, then using a recursive grep into all of the sub folders from src. It was somewhat painful and I think it missed some things.
I also have to check triggers, classes, page layouts, and any other code for these fields too.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Change Guru?  That is the only app i have found that will tell me where a field is being used vs how much data the field contains.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty old thread but adding another option. I have a free and open source app that scans the fields in your Org and returns the components it's used in (Workflows, Processes, Page Layouts, Apex etc).

Keep in mind that returning fields in Apex and VF is not 100% accurate, as a field with the same API name on different objects would return as being found in a class, even though it might not (as others have mentioned).

Also, it can take quite a while to run on large Orgs.

App: http://schemalister.herokuapp.com/

Source Code: https://github.com/benedwards44/schemalister

Answer (score 0):

I have a local java tool that does that but accuracy is ~95% and does not cover reports, email templates, LEX comps at this point.

https://github.com/shazibm91/ReferenceDetective